# How to display eslint errors in Visual Studio 2019 Error list

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, msbuild, eslint

Having SPA application with Angular and .net core web api, I would like to apply some typescript code style, so all of my team mates write code in same style. TSLint which is default linter shipped with angular is deprecated (as mentioned on theirs [github page](https://github.com/palantir/tslint)) so I went through tslint recomendations an try to use [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint). It was easy to add it to the project and run manually from cmd/powerShell. 
Now I want to run lint after msbuild so I added after build step in csproj file

```
<Target Name="typescript-eslint" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npx eslint --ext .ts"/>
</Target>
```

Which is works fine, but errors appeared in Error List window not helpful at all.[image]
I wonder is there a way to output errors in same way as it will be regular .net compilation error, so I can double click on error and quickly navigate to it.

Comment: Did you do any other operation to your project? If these files are already imported in your project by my solution and still face the same error, you should try to close VS, delete  the hidden `.vs` folder,`bin` ,`obj` folder and then restart VS again.

Answer (score 2):

TSLint is deprecated. You can do the following:

- Install ESLint via npm.
- Amend your build script to the following:

```
<Target Name="RunESLint" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="npx eslint $(SpaRoot) --format visualstudio"></Exec>
</Target>
```

The key is in the `--format` option.

Comment: I changed configuration a bit and now it works, but errors are duplicated. My configuration: <Target Name="RunESLint" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npx eslint --format visualstudio --quiet src/**/*.ts"></Exec>
  </Target>

Answer (score 0):

> How to display eslint errors in Visual Studio 2019 Error list

**First if all**, VS cannot detect and specifically analyze external files and **Error List window** has no right to obtain the specific information of the error in the external file.

**Further, you should make sure you have referenced `typescript-eslint` folder in your project.**

**1)** Using **Add Existing Item** to import `typescript-eslint` folder into your project.

**2)** add these at the bottom of the `xxx.csproj` file to referenced these:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<SpaRoot>xxx\xxx\typescript-eslint-master\</SpaRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="typescript-eslint" AfterTargets="Build">
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npx eslint --ext .ts"/>
</Target>
```

If you have done these and still face the same error, it is quite strange and I think whether you did any extra operation or the project itself.

**Also**, I have downloaded your link's file `typescript-eslint` and use your target and this defined property, I built the project without any errors.

And if you did any operation about your project files, it will be caught by the error list and locate the error.

**Suggestion**

close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin`, `obj` folder and then restart your project again.

**In addition**, if you did any other target operation to cause this issue, you could share with us.

**Update 1**

I have made a full description about the possible situation and thanks for your patience.

**Besides**, all of these above is due to these files are handled by VS IDE.

Error list can locate the specific errors from the referenced files handled by **VS IDE**.

**However**, your errors are from external CMD command line, the whole errors are just errors returned by CMD.

**And** VS intelligently judges whether your CMD command is correct, but the error returned by the specific execution steps, VS can display, but can not capture the specific location.

And VS does not have the job to catch specific errors for third-party tools.

**Conclusion**

**So you cannot get what you want from Error List in your situation.**

Comment: This not what I'm looking for, steps which described in your answer not related to my actual request - "I wonder is there a way to output errors in same way as it will be regular .net compilation error, so I can double click on error and quickly navigate to it."

Comment: Thanks for your patience and previous content  just perfects every possible situation. You can not get what you want from `Error List`. Since the errors are the results obtained after `CMD` processing. And `VS Error List` locates the specific errors which handled by `VS IDE`. Since `CMD` and VS are two different tools, VS does not have the job to receive `CMD` errors.